# is sjcl.encrypt using AES or SHA256

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, sha256, sjcl

I'm using the [SJCL library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/)  to encrypt/decrypt messages. The question I have is that I don't know which is used AES or SHA256

Here is my code:

```
var h = sjcl.codec.hex, count = 2048 ;
salt = h.fromBits(sjcl.random.randomWords('10','0'));
var key = h.fromBits( sjcl.misc.pbkdf2(somePassword, h.toBits(salt), count) ) ;
```

Next I can encrypt/decrypt like

```
var encMessage = sjcl.encrypt(key, message) ;
sjcl.decrypt(key, encMessage) ;
```

AES or SHA256 or something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pbkdf2` for key generation is using `HMAC` with `SHA256`. But the default encryption key size with sjcl for `AES-CCM` is only `128` bits. If you want `AES-CCM-256`, I think you need to do the following, you also don't have to call `pbkdf2` directly.

```
var encMessage =sjcl.encrypt(somePassword,message,{count:2048,salt:salt,ks:256});
```

Answer (score 6):

SHA256 and AES are 2 different types of algorithms.

SHA256 is a cryptography hash function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

AES is a encryption algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

So in your case when using encryption you are in fact using AES.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a cursory inspection of [the source](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/doc/symbols/src/core_convenience.js.html), I'd suggest it is using AES in [CCM mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode).

The [SJCL homepage](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) explains the cryptographic techniques used, although admittedly the per-function documentation does not explain it at all.