# AES-CMAC module for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, aes, cmac

Is there a Node.js module that handles AES-CMAC ([RFC 4493](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493))?

I've been searching around NPM, Google, and the like, but haven't found one. Somebody within my company built one that wraps [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) as a C++ addon for Node.js, but unfortunately it doesn't build on Windows (depends on `make`). Just looking for possible alternatives.

This is similar to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150250/how-can-i-generate-cmac-aes-in-javascript), but I'm hoping for a Node.js specific implementation instead of a plain JavaScript one. Ideally something that makes use of Node's crypto library or a C/C++ addon for performance.

It seems like it wouldn't be too hard to build one, but I'd like to avoid doing so if there is already one out there.

Comment: can you build using cygwin?

Comment: One of the devs on my team is currently experimenting with using cygwin. Another dev is looking at the possibility of creating an alternate for `make` on Windows to make it more `node-gyp` friendly. But I figured I'd ask this question to see if anyone else might have needed AES-CMAC in Node.js and already built something.

Comment: Have you got solution for this? if you got any solution, please let me know

Comment: @Piraba yes! See below. I finally finished up my own implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I couldn't find anything, I ended up creating my own module: [node-aes-cmac](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-aes-cmac)

As I learned more, I discovered that RFC 4493 is specific for 128 bit keys (AES128). But it references the [NIST Special Publication 800-38B](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38B/SP_800-38B.pdf) which gave the additional information I needed to support 192 and 256 bit keys as well.